# Error while creating a loop with an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, loops

I am having a problem in running a loop. 
There is an ndarray `d` with values `array(['3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '1.0'], dtype=object).`

I want to create a loop in which the value of `i` (in the loop)  becomes "3.0", "2.0" ... (the values of array d) and get the output accordingly.

Here is the code, I am trying to run:

The value of d is:

```
array(['3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '1.0'], dtype=object)
```

The type of d is **numpy.ndarray**.
 The type of d[0] is **str**

```
d = final_data.attribute1.unique()

for i in d:
    d = final_data.attribute1.unique()
    attributes = [1, 2]
    a = final_data[final_data['attribute1'] == i]
    b = a.attribute1.groupby(a.ordered_unordered).count()
    c = a.attribute1.count()
    print('\nthe total number of customers who clicked products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}'.format(attributes[0], d[0], c))
    print('the number of customers who clicked but didn\'t order products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}:' .format(attributes[0] ,d[0], b[0]))
    print('the number of customers who clicked and ordered products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}:' .format(attributes[0] ,d[0], b[1]))
    print(type(i))
    i += 1
```

and the error of the loop is"

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

I also tried to convert output of d as float/int in the following way:

```
d = final_data.attribute1.unique().astype(float)

for i in d:
    d = final_data.attribute1.unique()
    attributes = [1, 2]
    a = final_data[final_data['attribute1'] == i]
    b = a.attribute1.groupby(a.ordered_unordered).count()
    c = a.attribute1.count()
    print('\nthe total number of customers who clicked products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}'.format(attributes[0], d[0], c))
    print('the number of customers who clicked but didn\'t order products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}:' .format(attributes[0] ,d[0], b[0]))
    print('the number of customers who clicked and ordered products with attribute {}, rating {} are: {}:' .format(attributes[0] ,d[0], b[1]))
    print(type(i))
    i += 1
```

then the error is:

```
KeyError: 0.0
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

when i convert 'd' into float or int, it takes the value of 'i' as 0.0 (I don't know its reason).

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We expect an independent, minimal example to reproduce your error.  Include your entire error message, not merely the text line.

Comment: Can you print type(d)? It seems that it is a float and therefore you don't need the d[0], but rather d.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the output of d"?  `d` is a variable; it holds a value.  It does not produce "output".

Comment: Hi, i tried to modify it. I hope it will be more clear now. The type(d) is numpy ndarray. Yes, i agree, it is value of d, not an output. The problem is, the values of d are not fitting into loop (in place of i) and is producing error.

Comment: the type of d[0] is str.

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

```
d = array(['3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '1.0'], dtype=object)
```

and want to access the values in a loop? Use enumerate:

```
for i,x in enumerate(d):
    print('index:' + str(i))
    print('value:' + str(x))
```

Comment: Nope, my bad English. I want to provide the values of array d, to a loop. The loop above has a line 
a = final_data[final_data['attribute1'] == i]

In this line, the value of 'i' should be replaced with the values of array 'd' one by one and produce output.

Comment: What do you mean by 'one by one and produce output'?